@phpstan-ignore does not work as expected
I'm working on a Laravel project and there happens to be a code snippet like this:
sprintf("%s %s", __('foo.bar.buzz'), __('foo.bar.baz'));

Note that the __ function is a helper function from Laravel. The PHPDoc comment for the __ function includes the line @return string|array|null.
This trigger a phpstan error since sprintf cannot take an array as one of its optional parameters.
:49    Parameter #2 ...$values of function sprintf expects bool|float|int|string|null, array|string|null given.
:49    Parameter #3 ...$values of function sprintf expects bool|float|int|string|null, array|string|null given.

I added phpstan-ignore lines on the problematic code so it becomes
sprintf("%s %s",
    __('foo.bar.buzz'),  /* @phpstan-ignore argument.type */
    __('foo.bar.baz')    /* @phpstan-ignore argument.type */
);

and the error went away on my local.
However, when I push the changes to a remote GitLab repo, the errors still occured on the GitLab CI. I can make sure each __ function calls never returns an array.
Is there a workaround for this issue?

It’s better to report issues like these on PHPStan’s GitHub repository.

@OndřejMirtes yeah true, but I was hoping for a quicker response here

You'd definitely get a faster response on GitHub :)

@OndřejMirtes haha true you already replied on my issue there!

After checking the phpstan version used in the GitLab CI, I found out that it's using v1.8.11 while I have v1.11.8 on my local. Apparently /* @phpstan-ignore argument.type */ does not work on the former version. Changing it to /* @phpstan-ignore-line */ solved the problem.
I posted the same problem on the phpstan's Github here
